# Access: autocompiled field in table (not query)

Tags: ms-access

I would like to put an auto-lookup field in my `Table2` but I am not pretty sure that it is possible.

What I need is that, if I put `alex` in `Table2.Field3`, the field `Table2.[Autocompiled field]` have to take the value from `Table1.Address`.

Of course, if in the future I change `Table1.Address`, `Table2.[Autocompiled field]` should be automatically updated.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I would recommend to do not use lookup fields in tables at all, it more confuses users than helps http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm. Required functionality can be implemented in the form easily , don't do this in table

Comment: If you need to update another field based on information from another table without using forms, you can use table data macro functionality, create After Update data macro

Comment: You should neither store the names nor the addresses in Table2, the only thing that should be stored to reference a row in Table1 is the ID. To display both  name and address in one row and to be able to edit the data, use a form.